# Posting File data to a server?

Tags: android, image, http, postman, posting

How to send this format of data to a server?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just encode it to Base64.

Try this,

```
    private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file) {
    String encodedfile = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
        encodedfile = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encodedfile;
}
```